# Redirect URL if value ACF matches URL slug of page

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, advanced-custom-fields

I could use some help with something I try to achieve. We have a WordPress custom post type with vacancies and all those vacancies have a unique ID like 'P563328-18'. The URL of a single vacancie is like this:

https://example.com/vacancies/vacancie-title-p563328-18/

The vacancie ID's are stored in a ACF (custom field) 'vacancie_id' and I got a code like this to get all vacancie ID's:

```
<?php
$posts = get_posts(array(
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'post_type' => 'vacancies',
    'meta_key' => 'vacancie_id'
));

if($posts)
{
    foreach($posts as $post)
    {
        echo the_field('vacancie_id');
    }
}
?>
```

I know this is kind of useless for what I want to achieve but then you have an idea.

I want to create an automatic 301 redirect when somebody tries to visit this URL:
https://example.com/redirect/P563328-18

The server is redirecting this URL to the vacancie with that unique ID like:
https://example.com/vacancies/vacancie-title-p563328-18/

Is something like this possible and can somebody point me in the right direction on how I can achieve this?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

The answer of Tom made me think and the first URL that needs to get the redirect is a 404.

So basically what I want to achieve that when the 404 has a url like this:
https://example.com/redirect/P563328-18

redirect it to a vacancie post that has a slug that matches P563328-18.
https://example.com/vacancies/vacancie-title-p563328-18/

Answer (score 0):

Is your first URL valid or generates it a 404?

I`m not really a fan of plugins, but this one works quite good on some of my pages to serve this cause:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-404-auto-redirect-to-similar-post/

Just try it out, it finds a similar post and generates a 301 redirection to that post automatically.

If your first url does not generate a 404 then you could deny access with a .htacess file in the /redirect/ directory, like:

```
Deny from all
ErrorDocument 404 "/errors/404.html"
```

Regards Tom

Comment: Hello Tom, the first URL is a 404 and the plug-in you are suggesting is good when it is the title that has to get a redirect but it has to search for the ID in the URL and if there is a match then redirect to a page with that ID in it.

Comment: But your answer make me think, will edit my question